# Associate Data With HTML Element (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I need to associate some data with an HTML Element, hopefully avoiding any memory leaks. Obviously a simple solution would be to throw some kind of identifier on the element, and then create a dictionary mapping that identifier to the data I need. However, this is in a javascript library that users will add to their page, thus I don't have control over when elements are added or removed.

What I'm looking to do is associate data with an HTML element while it's on the page, while allowing for that data to be GC'd when/if the element is removed. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve writing my own periodic GC to clean up orphaned data? Is it safe to add properties to HTML elements?

Comment: Does this help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes ?

Comment: For anyone wondering like me, @Rakesh_Kumar was linking to information on data attributes. I second that suggestion; it's exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Attribute approach**

You can store data in elements using custom `data-*` attributes.

This has the limitation that you can only store strings, but you can use JSON to store plain objects or arrays (not by reference).

To avoid conflicts with other code, it would be a good idea to include the name of your library in the attribute.

They can be set directly in the HTML:

```html
<div data-mylibrary-foo="bar"></div>
```

And they can be read or written with JavaScript:

```js
element.getAttribute('data-mylibrary-foo');        // read  (old way)
element.setAttribute('data-mylibrary-foo', 'bar'); // write (old way)
element.dataset.mylibraryFoo;                      // read  (new way)
element.dataset.mylibraryFoo = 'bar';              // write (new way)
```

They can also be read by CSS, using some attribute selector.

**Property approach**

This is much more flexible than the attribute approach, allowing to store arbitrary data in your element.

To avoid conflicts with other code, better wrap all properties in an object with the name of your library:

```js
element.mylibrary = {};
element.mylibrary.foo = 'bar';
```

The problem is that a future HTML standard could define `mylibrary` as a native property, so there could be problems.

**Symbol approach**

ECMAScript 6 introduces [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), which can be used as properties. The advantage is that each symbol has an unique identity, so you don't need to worry about some other library or a future standard using the same properties as your code.

```
var foo = Symbol("foo");
element[foo] = 'bar';
```

**WeakMap approach**

ECMAScript 6 introduces [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)s, which allow you to associate data with objects in a way that, if the objects are no longer referenced anywhere else, they will be garbage collected.

Like the property approach, they allow you to store arbitrary data.

Since the data is not stored in the elements themselves, there is no risk of conflicts.

```js
var allData = new WeakMap();
var data1 = allData.get(element1) || {}; // read
data1.foo = "bar";
allData.set(element1, data1);            // write
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Is the property approach safe? It's certainly the easiest, but I have heard it's not all that safe.

Comment: @ColinM Not completely safe. Probably, other codes won't attempt to read `mylibrary`, if the name of your library is enough specific and isn't a standard property. But a future spec could standardize it, so then it could break things.

Comment: "The advantage is that each symbol has an unique identity". This doesn't really matter in that case because the symbol will be converted to a string and at least in Chrome this would always lead to 'Symbol(foo)', which means it would be the same to simply do element['Symbol(foo)'] = {}. WeakMap seems to be the most robust way if you can support modern browsers only.

Comment: @rosenfeld Symbol keys are not converted to strings.

Comment: @chocolateboy thanks for the heads up, I could just confirm and I found it surprising, but a good one for sure :) This opens up quite some possibilities I haven't thought about when using objects as hashes :)

Answer (score 1):

An HTML element in JavaScript is just a JavaScript object, so you can certainly add arbitrary properties to it. JavaScript will handle the garbage collection just fine.

The `data-` attribute is another option and might be a better choice if your properties are strings; their values will be visible in the DOM (which might be a good thing for debugging). If your properties are themselves objects, then you'd have to stringify them (and reverse the process to retrieve their values).

Comment: Well, HTMLElement in javascript are actually host objects, not just javascript objects. I have heard some issues with arbitrarily attaching properties to them (including memory leak issues in IE). But, stringifying the objects and associating them with `dataset` or `data-` properties makes sense. Don't know why I didn't think of simply stringifying before.